# How to get Ghidra to show `PUSH LAB_xxx` in Decompile view

Tags: ghidra, delphi

I am new to using Ghidra and I am trying to reverse engineer an x86 Windows executable written in Delphi Pascal.

I believe I am seeing a problem with the analysis of Try Finally blocks and I'd like to understand current limitations or my own misunderstandings.

TL;DR: How can I get Ghidra to recognize that `LAB_004c9a4c` is part of the same function above it?

Ghidra shows the function ending at `004c9a44` with the RET.

The jump at `004c9a45` is a kind of Finally handler.

The problem is that the `PUSH LAB_004c9a4c` at `004c9a31` is never represented anywhere in the Decompile view.

The analysis into `LAB_004c9a4c` and past depends on being included in the same function as above (otherwise treating `LAB_004c9a4c`  as its own function causes A LOT of headaches: a ton of unaff_EBP variables, etc. and it seems like the wrong approach)

Is there a way I can achieve this? I have played around with some analysis settings in Ghidra, but nothing ever worked.

```
...

                     LAB_004c9a29                                    XREF[1]:     004c9a1f(j)  
004c9a29 33 c0           XOR        param_1,param_1
004c9a2b 5a              POP        param_2
004c9a2c 59              POP        ECX
004c9a2d 59              POP        ECX=>LAB_004c9a45
004c9a2e 64 89 10        MOV        dword ptr FS:[param_1],param_2
004c9a31 68 4c 9a        PUSH       LAB_004c9a4c
         4c 00
004c9a36 80 7d ff 00     CMP        byte ptr [EBP + local_5],0x0
004c9a3a 74 08           JZ         LAB_004c9a44
004c9a3c 8b 45 f8        MOV        param_1,dword ptr [EBP + local_c]
004c9a3f e8 20 0a        CALL       FUN_0047a464                                     undefined FUN_0047a464(int * * p
         fb ff
                     LAB_004c9a44                                    XREF[1]:     004c9a3a(j)  
004c9a44 c3              RET
                     LAB_004c9a45                                    XREF[2]:     FUN_004c9290:004c94ae(*), 
                                                                                  FUN_004c9290:004c9a2d(*)  
004c9a45 e9 c6 ac        JMP        FUN_00404710                                     undefined4 FUN_00404710(undefine
         f3 ff
                     -- Flow Override: CALL_RETURN (CALL_TERMINATOR)
004c9a4a eb              ??         EBh
004c9a4b ea              ??         EAh
                     LAB_004c9a4c                                    XREF[1]:     FUN_004c9290:004c9a31(*)  
004c9a4c 80 7d ff 00     CMP        byte ptr [EBP + -0x1],0x0
004c9a50 74 14           JZ         LAB_004c9a66
004c9a52 8b 4d ec        MOV        ECX,dword ptr [EBP + -0x14]
004c9a55 2b 4d e4        SUB        ECX,dword ptr [EBP + -0x1c]
004c9a58 83 e9 40        SUB        ECX,0x40
004c9a5b 8b 55 f8        MOV        EDX,dword ptr [EBP + -0x8]
004c9a5e 8b 45 f4        MOV        EAX,dword ptr [EBP + -0xc]
004c9a61 e8 3a 07        CALL       FUN_0047a1a0                                     undefined FUN_0047a1a0(undefined
         fb ff
...
```

[image]

Comment: IDA Pro does analyze this code correctly (treats as a single function).

This issue may be related to Ghidra not understanding SEH:
https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/2477